# bash unable to export the variable to script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh

i am stuck with my piece of code any help is appreciated. This is the piece of code i am executing from jenkins.

```
#!/bin/bash
aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].[Tags[?Key==`Name`].Value|[0],PrivateIpAddress]' --output text | column  | grep devtools > devtools
ip=`awk '{print $2}' devtool`
echo $ip

ssh ubuntu@$ip -n "aws s3 cp s3://bucket/$userlistlocation . --region eu-central-1"



cd builds/${BUILD_NUMBER}/
scp * ubuntu@$ip:/home/ubuntu


if [ $port_type == "normal" ]; then
if [ $duplicate_value == "no" ]; then
if [ $userlist == "uuid" ]; then
ssh ubuntu@$ip -n "export thread_size='"'$thread_size'"'; filename=$(echo $userlistlocation | sed -E 's/.*\/(.*)$/\1/') ; echo $filename ; echo filename='"'$filename'"'; chmod +x uuidwithduplicate.sh; ./uuidwithduplicate.sh"



fi
fi
fi
fi
```

userlistlocation --> is an user input it can be in any format /rahul/december/file.csv or simply it can be file.csv.

Through sed command i am able to get the output and stored in "filename" variable.

But when i try to echo $filename it's printing as echo $filename it should print as file.csv

this file.csv will be the source file for one more script  to run i.e for uuidwithduplicate.sh

both userlistlocation and thread_size are specified through Jenkins job parameters.

I am not facing issues while exporting thread_size, only issue is with filename.

It's just printing echo $filename --> it should print file.csv

Comment: Do a `echo ull="$userlistlocation" bn="$fbname"` after calculating the basename.

Comment: Always quote  filename: `fbname=$( basename "$userlistlocation" )`. But not sure, if it helps here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Breaking down the `ssh` command:

```
ssh ubuntu@$ip -n "export thread_size='"'$thread_size'"'; filename=$(echo $userlistlocation | sed -E 's/.*\/(.*)$/\1/') ; echo $filename ; echo filename='"'$filename'"'; chmod +x uuidwithduplicate.sh; ./uuidwithduplicate.sh"
```

Into segments of single/double quoted items

- "export thread_size='"
- '$thread_size'
- "@'; filename=$(echo $userlistlocation | sed -E 's/.*/(.*)$/\1/') ; echo $filename ; echo filename='@"
- '$filename'
- "'; chmod +x uuidwithduplicate.sh; ./uuidwithduplicate.sh"

Note: On the 3rd token, an '@' was added between double quotes and single quote to make it more readable. Not part of the command.

On surface few issues:

- The `'$thread_size'` should be `"$thread_size"` to enable expansion
- The 'echo $filename' is in double quote, resulting in expansion on the local host, where as setting `filename=$(echo ...)` is executed on the remote host.
- There are two `echo` for filename, not sure why

Proposed solution is to move the setting of filename to the local host (simplify command), and move the thread_size into double quotes. It is possible to put complete command into single double-quoted item:

```
filename=$(echo $userlistlocation | sed -E 's/.*\/(.*)$/\1/')

ssh localhost -n "export thread_size='$thread_size'; echo '$filename' ; echo filename='$filename'; chmod +x uuidwithduplicate.sh; ./uuidwithduplicate.sh"
```

Comment: Can you provide more details, error message, etc. try adding ‘set -x’ to the script. What is the output ?

Comment: Thanks for the solution but it didn't worked. When i am executing the way you mentioned below is the output i am getting 

ssh ubuntu@$ip -n "export thread_size='3';  echo '$filename' ; chmod +x uuidwithduplicate.sh; ./uuidwithduplicate.sh"

Interesting part is it able print thread_size variable but not able to print $filename. Entire script is run by single user. 

That User able to pick thread_size which is an (Parameterized) variable in jenkins but not the variable ($filename) which is  part of script

Comment: Can you do echo $filename after the assignment filename=... ?

Comment: Very strange. Are you using running from a terminal, or from Jenkins job ? Does it work from a terminal ?

Comment: I am running from Jenkins job. "Send files or execute commands over ssh" I am keeping script over there for execution.

Comment: filename=$(echo $userlistlocation | sed -E 's/.*\/(.*)$/\1/')
if i do echo $filename it's printing as same it's not printing the value assigned to it

Comment: Issue is resolved, when i am echoing though it's printing variable name but it's exporting.